# AndroidアプリでBitlyへのpost送信がうまくいきません

Tags: java, android

httpRequestのurlは下のが入ります。
urlにpost送信をし、そこからjsonが返ってくるのでlinkを取得したいです。
取得したlinkをsetしたいんですがなにも入力されず、何が悪いのかもわかりません。

```
url= "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"

void httpRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        final TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine2);
        //OkHttpClinet生成
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        //request生成
        MediaType MIMEType= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create (MIMEType,"{\n" +
                "    \"long_url\"https:",  \n" +
                "    \"domain\": \"bit.ly\",  \n" +
                "    \"group_guid\": \"guid\" \n" +
                "}  ");

        Request request = new Request.Builder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {token}").url(url).post(requestBody).build();


        //非同期リクエスト
        client.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new Callback() {

                    //エラーのとき
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Hoge",e.getMessage());
                    }

                    //正常のとき
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                        //response取り出し
                        final String jsonStr = response.body().string();
                        Log.d("Hoge","jsonStr=" + jsonStr);

                        //JSON処理
                        try{
                            //jsonパース
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                            final String url = json.getString("link");

                            //親スレッドUI更新
                            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    textView.setText(url);

                                }
                            });


                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("Hoge",e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: [Bitly API (4.0.0)](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference)の各言語の例に書かれている内容と等価なもの(変える必要のあるものは変えておく)を作成して呼び出してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 同じように変えたつもりなんですけど上手くいかないです。個人的にはaddheaderの所が調べても同設定したらいいのかよくわからなかったので、そこかもしれないです

Comment: 使おうとしている各パラメータを基に、いったん`cURL`コマンドで試してみるとか？

Comment: 'Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}'
これにheaderを設定しないといけないんですけど、
addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {token}")
この記述であってますか？

Comment: `{TOKEN}`の部分は、その文字列そのものではなく、bitlyに発行してもらうアクセストークンが入るはずです。[bitlyのAPIアクセストークンを取得できない？パスワード入力の場所が変わってた](https://mahoro7.net/bitly-api-accesstoken-9465), [Bitly API - How to Generate OAuth2 Token to integrate with Bit.ly API V4 and create a shortened url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59431374/9014308), こちらはJavaScriptですが [短縮URL生成サイト「bit.ly」のAPIv4へのマイグレーションの方法](https://another.rocomotion.net/15831289905945.html)

Comment: それはわかってるので大丈夫です。

Comment: いましたら403がでて、FORBIDDENらしいのですが
値がおかしいとかですかね

Comment: 何か他の言語なりアプリなりで上手く動作するものがあるなら、ネットワークアナライザとかでデータの差異を調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: pythonでの例を見て、Pythonでしてみたらできました。
ですが、haedersでヘッダーに複数の値を入れる方法がJavaでわかりません。

Comment: これがヒントになるかも。[Equivalent of curl command in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49901102/9014308)

Comment: 完全に違う方法にはなりましたが、できました！

Comment: それは良かったです。なるべくなら、出来たものを自己回答しておいてください。